# Term by term differentiation of series of functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, uniform-convergence

Show that the series for which the sum of first $n$ terms $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$ cannot be differentiated term-by-term at $x = 0$. What happens at $x \neq  0$?

As-

Here we are given with the sequence of partial sums. We know that $(f_n) \to f $ uniformly on $S$ iff 
$$ \lim [ \sup\{ |f(x) - f_n(x) : x \in S \} ] = 0 \; \; $$Here note that $f \equiv 0$. 
$$ |f_n - f | = f_n = \frac{nx}{1 + n^2x^2 } \implies  f_n'(x) = \frac{n(1 + n^2x^2) - nx(2xn^2)}{(1 + n^2x^2)^2}$$
and 
$$ f'_n(x) = 0 \iff x = \frac{1}{n}, \frac{-1}{n} $$
Now observe that
$$ f_n\bigg(  \frac{1}{n} \bigg) = \frac{1}{2}  \implies  \lim \sup|f_n - f|  = \frac{1}{2} \neq 0$$Therefore we conclude that $f_n$ does not converges uniformly to $0$ and hence we can say that series can't be differentiated term by term.

Am i correct? What about any other point?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show? Neither the series nor the derivative series converges for $x\neq 0.$

Comment: So  can we directly say that series can't be differentiated term by term at $x \neq 0$?